# Why unspecified lambda return types don't always work?

Tags: c++, lambda, return-value, auto, c++20

I don't understand why unspecified lambda return types will work sometimes but not all the time.
In particular in this piece of code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept NoArgFunc = 
requires (T f) {
    f();
};

auto curry(NoArgFunc auto&& f) {
    return f();    
}

auto curry(auto&& f) {
    return [=](auto&& ...x) {
        return curry([=](auto&& ...xs) -> decltype(f(x..., xs...)) {
                return f(x..., xs...);
        });
    };
}


int main() {
    auto f = [](auto a, auto b, auto c, auto d, auto e) {
        return a * b * c * d * e;
    };

    std::cout << curry(f)(1, 2)()(3)(4, 5);
}
```

This code compiles and outputs `120` as expected, yet if I don't specify `decltype(f(x..., xs...))` for the lambda in the recursive return of the `curry` function, it does not compiles and complains that I gave 2 arguments instead of 5 which would mean the curryfication did not work. Why is that?

I have tried to search and understand why this return type specification is necessary without success.

Here is the complete error message when the decltype is not provided:

```c
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> [with auto:14 = {}]’:
main.cpp:31:6:   required from ‘auto curry(auto:11&&) [with auto:11 = curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)>]’
main.cpp:40:21:   required from ‘curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]’
main.cpp:52:31:   required from here
main.cpp:41:25: error: no match for call to ‘(const main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>) (const int&, const int&)’
   41 |                 return f(x..., xs...);
      |                        ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:48:14: note: candidate: ‘template<class auto:15, class auto:16, class auto:17, class auto:18, class auto:19> main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>’
   48 |     auto f = [](auto a, auto b, auto c, auto d, auto e) {
      |              ^
main.cpp:48:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:41:25: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 2 provided
   41 |                 return f(x..., xs...);
      |                        ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> [with auto:14 = {const int&}]’:
main.cpp:41:25:   recursively required from ‘curry<curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> [with auto:14 = {const int&}]’
main.cpp:41:25:   required from ‘curry<curry<curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> [with auto:14 = {}]’
main.cpp:31:6:   required from ‘auto curry(auto:11&&) [with auto:11 = curry<curry<curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)>]’
main.cpp:40:21:   required from ‘curry<curry<curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int}]’
main.cpp:52:36:   required from here
main.cpp:41:25: error: no match for call to ‘(const main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>) (const int&, const int&, const int&)’
main.cpp:48:14: note: candidate: ‘template<class auto:15, class auto:16, class auto:17, class auto:18, class auto:19> main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>’
   48 |     auto f = [](auto a, auto b, auto c, auto d, auto e) {
      |              ^
main.cpp:48:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:41:25: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 3 provided
   41 |                 return f(x..., xs...);
      |                        ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
➜  experiments g++10 -std=c++20 main.cpp
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> [with auto:14 = {}]’:
main.cpp:31:6:   required from ‘auto curry(auto:11&&) [with auto:11 = curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)>]’
main.cpp:40:21:   required from ‘curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]’
main.cpp:52:31:   required from here
main.cpp:41:25: error: no match for call to ‘(const main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>) (const int&, const int&)’
   41 |                 return f(x..., xs...);
      |                        ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:48:14: note: candidate: ‘template<class auto:15, class auto:16, class auto:17, class auto:18, class auto:19> main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>’
   48 |     auto f = [](auto a, auto b, auto c, auto d, auto e) {
      |              ^
main.cpp:48:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:41:25: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 2 provided
   41 |                 return f(x..., xs...);
      |                        ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> [with auto:14 = {const int&}]’:
main.cpp:41:25:   recursively required from ‘curry<curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> [with auto:14 = {const int&}]’
main.cpp:41:25:   required from ‘curry<curry<curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> [with auto:14 = {}]’
main.cpp:31:6:   required from ‘auto curry(auto:11&&) [with auto:11 = curry<curry<curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)>]’
main.cpp:40:21:   required from ‘curry<curry<curry<main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>&>::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int, int}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {}]::<lambda(auto:14&& ...)> >::<lambda(auto:13&& ...)> [with auto:13 = {int}]’
main.cpp:52:36:   required from here
main.cpp:41:25: error: no match for call to ‘(const main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>) (const int&, const int&, const int&)’
main.cpp:48:14: note: candidate: ‘template<class auto:15, class auto:16, class auto:17, class auto:18, class auto:19> main()::<lambda(auto:15, auto:16, auto:17, auto:18, auto:19)>’
   48 |     auto f = [](auto a, auto b, auto c, auto d, auto e) {
      |              ^
main.cpp:48:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:41:25: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 3 provided
   41 |                 return f(x..., xs...);
      |                        ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decltype` serves as SFINAE too.

Else `[](auto&& ...xs){/**/}` is callable with any parameters, but might produce hard error.

So, is a viable argument to `auto curry(NoArgFunc auto&& f)`.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you. But I wonder how a compiler could handle this. Does it check if the function is valid with xs representing an increasing number of arguments until f(x..., xs...) is a valid function call? That would seem like quite a complex problem to solve.

Comment: For each call of `curry`, it has to decide the overload to call (best viable). `curry(f)(1, 2)()` is `curry([x1 = 1, x2 = 2](/*Empty pack*/) /*No ->decltype*/) {
                return f(x1, x2);`, that curry has the choice between `curry(NoArgFunc &&)` and less specialized `auto curry(auto&& f)`, so call erroneous `f(1, 2)`. I don't see the problematic call with 3 arguments though (maybe a continue on error to spot extra error, or I miss some overload resolutions).